# Fail to generate correct triangle mesh inside of a concaved polygon using scipy in Python

Tags: python, scipy, mesh, delaunay

I encountered a task in my work that where I need to create triangle mesh inside of several different polygons using Python. Though the polygons are segmentations of a convex hull, each segment itself is in concaved shape. When I tried to use scipy.spatial.Delaunay(), it appears that the algorithm assumes the polygon to be convex and ends up generating triangles outside of the concave hull area. The codes and resulted graph are below.

```
for i in range(len(mp)):
    dtri = np.array(mp[i])
    plt.scatter(dtri[:,0],dtri[:,1])
    plt.plot(np.array(fdc_seg[i])[:,0],np.array(fdc_seg[i])[:,1])
    tri = Delaunay(dtri,qhull_options="QJ")
    triang = mtri.Triangulation(dtri[:, 0],dtri[:, 1],triangles=tri.simplices)
    plt.triplot(dtri[:, 0], dtri[:, 1], tri.simplices,lw=0.5, color='red')
plt.show()
```

[polygon shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyHzN.png)
[resulted triangle mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzvzm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routine scipy.spatial.Delaunay() creates a triangulation of the convex hull of the points supplied to the algorithm, so these extra triangles are expected. To get the result that you are looking for, (1) you will need to hope to remove triangles outside your polygon and (2) you need to hope that the edges of your polygon all actually exist in the Delaunay triangulation.

An alternative would be to use [Triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) which has a several python wrappers, [here](https://rufat.be/triangle/index.html) and [here](https://mathema.tician.de/software/meshpy/). That code builds a constrained Delaunay triangulation of a polygon and removes the exterior triangles.

Comment: Thank you Alex, that was very informative. I solved the problem using Shapely library, to remove triangles outside the polygon by forming each triangle  as an individual polygon and see if it's in the original polygon. And thank you for sharing Triangle and Meshpy, although the reason I met the above issue was trying to replace Meshpy as the tri-mesh generator since it repeatedly crashes(for some reasons, it works better under Linux system). If you know the reason of which Meshpy crashes so much, please let me know as well. Thank you again for the help.